# Serial Communication of Raspberry pi 3 with HC-05 bluetooth module

Tags: python, uart

While transmitting int value from Arduino to raspberry pi3 using HC-05 Bluetooth module it receiving some garbage hex value like "/xc8" for 200.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate = 9600)
time.sleep(1)
while 1:
    x = ser.read(1) 
    print ("data",x)
```

Please suggest how to receive decimal data at raspbrrypi.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/xc8 is the hexidecimal equivalent of 200. You just need to convert it back to decimal. Assuming your values are integers, you can convert your hex value to an int like this:

`x = int("c8", 16)`